# I don't want to see hiding excel columns in power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I hid some columns in Excel (i dont want to delete them) and but I see them still in power query.
I don't want to see hiding excel columns in power query. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just remove them from the query?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.